# unexpected behavior in moment js when converting string to datetime in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I want to convert `'03/08/2017  01:00:01 '`to datetime object in node.js so that I can get the specific day and month in the date. eg : month is 08 and day is 03 for above example.

please refer the below code snippet, it gives me below result.

```
const myDate = moment('03/08/2017  01:00:01 '.trim(),  ['DD/MM/YYYY  hh:mm:ss'], true).utcOffset(0).toDate();
console.log(myDate); //result 2017-08-02T19:30:01.000Z
console.log(myDate.getUTCFullYear()); //result 2017
console.log(myDate.getUTCMonth()); //result 7
console.log(myDate.getUTCDay()); //result 4
```

further, I tried below code snippets. here I couldn't able to use `.toDate()` function to convert it to datetime object.

```
let date = moment.parseZone(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
console.log(date); // result 2017-08-03 01:00:01
```

here it gives the correct date but I couldn't able to extract the month from it.

```
let date_ = moment(new Date(date), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('LLL');
console.log(date_); // result August 3, 2017 1:00 AM
```

below code snippet also give the first result. I executed all of these lines in a single file

```
let _date = moment(new Date(date)).utc().toDate();
console.log(_date);// result 2017-08-02T19:30:01.000Z
console.log(_date.getUTCFullYear()); //result 2017
console.log(_date.getUTCMonth()); //result 7
console.log(_date.getUTCDay()); //result 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) states:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use
>   moment.utc() instead of moment().

so one possible approach would be to work in UTC and do:

```
const myDate2 = moment.utc('03/08/2017  01:00:01',  ['DD/MM/YYYY  hh:mm:ss'], true).toDate();
console.log(myDate2.getUTCDate());
console.log(myDate2.getUTCMonth() + 1);
console.log(myDate2.getUTCHours());
```

Note that in order to get the day number, one has to call `getUTCDate`, the [`getUTCDay/getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week instead. Also, the month number returned by `getMonth/getUTCMonth` is in the range `0-11` so one has to increment the result by one.

Alternatively, one can work in local date and do:

```
const myDate1 = moment('03/08/2017  01:00:01',  ['DD/MM/YYYY  hh:mm:ss'], true).toDate();
console.log(myDate1.getDate());
console.log(myDate1.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(myDate1.getHours());
```

Comment: this is the exact reason, I wasted more than 04 hours to understand this